# How to change the class using click and hovering

Tags: angularjs, mouseover, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, mouseleave

**View:**

```
<a ng-repeat="control in controls | filter:name" ng-href="#{{control.id}}" ng-click="restart(control.name)" ng-class="{active: control.name == selected}">{{control.name}}
```

**controller-** app.js

```
$scope.restart = function (controlName) {
    $scope.selected = controlName;
}
```

Here i have added the active class while clicking.how can i add the hover class using mouseover and remover the class using mouse-leave.

Comment: Use `ngMouseover` and `ngMouseleave`

Comment: I have used..but i want to add active class while clicking.and i want add the add the 'hover' class while hovering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested above, use ng-class with ng-mouseover and ng-mouseleave:

```
<div ng-class="class" ng-click="class='active'" ng-mouseover="class='hovering'" ng-mouseleave="class=''"></div>
```

This way, you'll have 3 event listener to a single variable (in a mutually exclusive way).

If you want to have both at the same time, use an array this way:

```
<div ng-class="[classClick, classHover]" ng-click="classClick='active'" ng-mouseover="classhover='hovering'" ng-mouseleave="classHover=''"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-class, ng-mouseover anf ng-mouseleave:

```
<div ng-class='{"classtoadd": add, "active": click, "hover": hover}' ng-mouseover="add=true;" ng-mouseleave="add=false" ng-click="click = true" ng-mouseover="hover = true"></div>
```

Thanks for your response. i want to add 'active' class while clicking.and i want add the add the class' hover' while 'hovering'

Comment: Thanks for your response. i want to add 'active' class while clicking.and i want add the add the class' hover' while 'hovering'